# Python (json) : TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, json, web.py

I want to read data from my database then create and return a json format to my python web server (web.py).But following code doesn't work and gives me this error:

TypeError: expected string or buffer

Switched between loads and load also dumps and dump (Which i cant understand why).As you understand i'm very new to both python and json format i will be very thankful if you help me out(saw many post about this problem but still cant figure out what to do)

```
def ara_json(str):
    web.header('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8', unique=True) 
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='arda', password='1', database='worddb')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    sqlq = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = '%s'" %str
    cursor.execute(sqlq)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    result=[]
    for row in rows:
            d = dict()
            d['name'] = row[0]
            d['type'] = row[1]
                result.append(d)
            subjects = json.loads(result).read()
        return json.dump(subjects , indent=4)


class json_isimbul:
    def GET(self,isim):
    web.header('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8', unique=True)    
    isim = isim.lower()
    return ara_json(isim)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/application.py", line 420, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/application.py", line 396, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "/home/arda/Downloads/arda/tmp/tornado/ps/sa2.py", line 98, in GET
    return ara_json(isim)
  File "/home/arda/Downloads/arda/tmp/tornado/ps/sa2.py", line 53, in ara_json
    subjects = json.loads(result).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Can you show the traceback of your exception? With just the type and short message, it's hard to know what part of your code is raising that error, and the traceback will show that very clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry . Just edited , hope you can understand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to change two lines and it will work fine.

1. remove this line: subjects = json.loads(result).read()
2. and do like this : return json.dumps(result , indent=4)

Hopefully, it will help you. :)

Comment: I did exactly this  as i wrote in first answer. Both answers helped a lot thanks

Answer (score 11):

`json.loads()` expects a string. The right way to do this is to first construct your data and use `json.dumps` which will give you a json object(a string actually). Hope this helps.

Comment: Strings *are* objects.  Everything in Python is an object.

Comment: yeah they are. But `json.dumps` returns json string and not json object. I just wanted to clarify that.

Comment: Thank You . I understand know it was purely unnecessary to use load.  json.dumps(result) gave me what i want . Had to study more ! :)